# Add tracking code to Ninja Forms submit button in WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have several specific landing pages as part of a WordPress website, that are used for AdWord campaigns. Within each of these pages there is a contact form, created by using the Ninja Forms plugin.

I need to add a specific onClick tag to each of the submit buttons for event tracking. Not using Google Analytics but Yell.com – as they are running and managing the campaigns.

Yell.com have sent me instructions, firstly to add a conversion tag to each of the pages – which I've done by using a WordPress plugin.

The next task is where I'm struggling.

The HTML code for the Submit button on the form is as below:

```
<input id="nf-field-62" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element " type="button" value="SUBMIT">
```

I need to amend this code to include the on-click handler based on the requirements for the Ninja Forms and add it to the Submit button on the page:

```
<input kenshoo_conv('residentialcontactform','value','orderId','promocode','GBP') id="nf-field-62" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element " type="button" value="SUBMIT">
```

I have found a topic in the Ninja form support which details how to add Google event tracking, by adding the following code to the footer.php:

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
    jQuery( document )
    .on('click', 'input[type=button]', function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'Email List', 'Subscribed', 'New Subscriber');
    });
  });
</script>
```

I know I can target the specific button by adding in the ID, but could I include the code required for the tracking into this too? If so, I guess I would need to repeat this script 10 times with each button id and specific tracking code?